# How to get Pull Requests associated with a Work Item via the Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-api-management, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-api-apps

I am trying to list all Pull Requests associated with a Work Item but according to [the Work Items API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) there doesn't seem to be a way to get it:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/123456/workitems?api-version=6.0
```

The above returns list of work items, such as:

```
{
  "count": 40,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "156267",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/_apis/wit/workItems/12345"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Now, if I still decide to query each returned work item I still don't see a Pull Request.
For example:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/xxx/_apis/wit/workItems/12345
```

The above returns a JSON object about updates done to the workitem, but this can be a commit, state update or comments.

Is there a way to get a list of PRs per work item?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `&$expand=relations`:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/xxx/_apis/wit/workItems/12345?$expand=relations
```

Now in the response you will get the linked PR under the `relations`.

Comment: Hi, I finally got time to test your answer today and it doesn't work for me. For example, I use the following URL: `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/wit/workItems/126461` I can see all workitems (albeit without the PR info) but when I add your answer `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/wit/workItems/126461&$expand=relations` I get "Page Not Found" error

Comment: @Displayname my mistake, it should be `?` before the `$expand` and not `&`, i fixed it.

Comment: A regular expression to get the id in the first group of the response would be: PullRequestId\/.*%2F(\d+)",